# flash as3 check event listener

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is their a way to check if an event listener already exists to remove it?

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickdownfunction);
```

Basically, I want to remove the listener, but sometimes it has already been removed, so I want to check if it exists and if it does, then remove it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out the `hasEventListener()` function from

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html#hasEventListener()

I am not really sure though why you want to do that check. Removing non existant listeners won't make Flash drop exceptions or errors, thus the check is just adding unneccessary overhead.

Answer (score 10):

you can't check if a specific function is registered as a listener, you can though check if a type is registered. This can be done with this:

```
hasEventListener(type:String):Boolean
```

Alternatively you can just call `removeEventListener`, if it's not registered it'll just ignore the call.

Hope that helps,

Comment: we have to check a spesific event sometimes. that is not cool.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code you need to remove the event listener only if it is active:

```
if(stage.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK))
     stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickdownfunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Fingers](http://filimanjaro.com/fingers):

```
 on(stage).click -= clickdownfunction;
```