# is it ok to call removeEventListener() twice?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

```
private function saveDatabase(obj:Object):void{
  database.setValue(obj);
  database.addEventListener( DatabaseReferenceEvent.VALUE_CHANGED, dbValueChanged );
}


private function dbValueChanged(event:DatabaseReferenceEvent):void {
  database.removeEventListener( DatabaseReferenceEvent.VALUE_CHANGED, dbValueChanged );

  //do something here

}

private function destroy():void{
  database.removeEventListener( DatabaseReferenceEvent.VALUE_CHANGED, dbValueChanged );
  // remove all other objects
}
```

In the above code sometimes due to latency issues, the value changed event may not get triggered. So while calling `destroy()` I am not sure if the event listener is removed or not? Is it ok to call it in `destroy()` even if it's removed in `dbValueChanged()`;

Comment: It's ok to remove event listener twice. You will not encounter any problems. BTW, if you add the same listener twice then remove it once — one will still stay subscribed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is of concern and you think there could be multiple listeners as Organis suggests you can check to see if the listener exists.

[flash as3 check event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157768/flash-as3-check-event-listener)